# JS: Are `load` events needed if you place your scripts at the end of the body?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it's redundant to wrap code in:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {})
```

if you already have your scripts loaded at the bottom of the `body` tag?
Wouldn't that already ensure the DOM has loaded, making a `load` event listener unnecessary?

Comment: You can also put the script in the `<head>` (so it gets downloaded quicker) and use the `defer` attribute instead

Comment: thanks.  Does using `defer` wait for DOM elements like photos to load?

Comment: No, it's pretty much identical to DOMContentLoaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. And, by placing the `script` at the end of the `body`, you actually reduce the complexity of the code and reduce the memory required to create and store an event handler. This is considered a best practice these days but it's not quite identical to setting up a `load` event handler. Instead, it's analogous to setting up a [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event handler.

One caveat though is when you need to defer your code until all the external content referenced by your DOM elements has finished downloading (like pictures). Then setting up the `load` event handler is the way to go.